# Utf8 encoding with MySQLdb on non-utf symbols

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am receiving an xml feed which has values such as:

```
<Theme>Valentine&#39;s Day</Theme>
<Copyright>&#169; Ventures. All Rights Reserved.</Copyright>
```

I need to parse the value and store it in a mysql database. What would be the best way to cleanse the values so I can insert `"Valentie's Day"`, `"<copyright symbol> Ventures. All Rights Reserved."`? There are about 20+ different marking like this.

Doing a straight `INSERT`, I'll get the following erro:

```
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xA9 1987...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse the XML with a real xml parser, you'll get Unicode strings as text.  You can then encode them with UTF-8:

```
title = text.encode('utf8')
```

and title will be writable into your database, though many details are still unclear because we don't know how you're writing to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Specify encoding and then ecode the string to `utf8`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
title = text.encode('utf8')
```

Comment: The file encoding is irrelevant here, it only affects how string literals are interpreted.